# How to do Either-Or on tables Efficiently and better performance?

Tags: sql, postgresql

It's easy to do Either-Or in the condition clause, what about on table level?

Have a complicated query business requirement can be depicted like:

- Parent must be satisfying lots of conditions with other foreign tables.
- then **Either** satisfying low_distribution_condition from *SonTable* **OR** low_distribution_condition from *DaughterTable*, for example wearing_glasss.

So

```
create table Parent (Pid integer, ..., CONSTRAINT p_pkey PRIMARY KEY (Pid))
create table Foreign1 (...)
...
create table Son (Pid intger, SonID integer, ...) create index s_pdx (Pid)
create table Daughter (Pid integer, DaughterID integer, ...) create index d_pdx (Pid)


select p.* 
from 
    (select Pid, ...
    from Parent 
    join Foreign1 on ...
    left join Foreign2 on ...) p
join 
    (select Pid, commonField1, ... from Son where son_wearing_glass
    union all  -- for performance of Either-Or
    select Pid, commonField1, ... from Daughter where daughter_wearing_glass) sg
on p.Pid = sg.Pid
```

`wearing_glass` is not a highly-distributed condition, index won't help and returns many rows. But breaking up `sg` and let each of them join maybe more efficient, this way `Son` and `Daughter` pre-filtered by `Pid` utilizing index and cuts down returning rows before wearing_glass:

```
select p.* 
from 
    (select Pid, ...
    from Parent 
    join Foreign1 on ...
    left join Foreign2 on ...) p
join 
    Son s on p.Pid = s.Pid where son_wearing_glass
Union all --or Union
select p.* 
from 
    (select Pid, ...
    from Parent 
    join Foreign1 on ...
    left join Foreign2 on ...) p
join 
    Daughter d on p.Pid = d.Pid where daughter_wearing_glass
```

The price can be doubling resources on `p`. Don't know how to do `exists` for Either-Or.

How to achieve better efficiency and performance?

Comment: If I  correctly understood your idea then  I suppose that `UNION` (not `UNION ALL`) is needed here. JOIN or EXISTS:  EXISTS would be better for cardinality but I think I would try use INTERSECT instead. That way it will be `fact_data_A INTERSECT condition_A UNION fact_data_B INTERSECT condition_B` and so on

Comment: "Either - or" in the English language typically means that you do *not* want both conditions to be true. Is that what you want here? I am not quite certain what you are asking here. Do you want us to rewrite your query? To be more beautiful? To be faster? To be correct, because your current query isn't?

Comment: @AlexYu I've updated my question, please feel free.

Comment: You would be better off having a single `child` table instead of separate `son` and `daughter` tables. Your contention that pre-filtering and joining to each  separately would be more efficient would seems false. UNION requires the `parent` table (along with `foreign1` and `foreign2` joins) to be processed twice. Perhaps the optimizer will notice they are the same, but I would not count on it (you could always run explain on both). Further it makes your queries (all of them?) more complicated. If you really have a need for viewing just sons or just daughters you can create views to do so.

Comment: @Belayer `son` and `daughter` are existings, a _View_ is a good idea.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Please help me rewrite this query for efficiency and performance. Thanks.

Comment: The best query depends on your data and your index definitions. You have to experiment. Use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` to analyze execution plans.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Agree, thank you